# How to deploy ASP.NET website (version prior to ASP.NET 5) to Linux server?

Tags: asp.net, linux

I am currently in process of identifying a mechanism to deploy ASP.NET websites to Linux server. I know this requires Apache to be installed on Linux, and can be achieved using Mono.

I found a lot many articles but they all are referring to ASP.NET version 5 (i believe, vNext). But couldn't find anything for a version prior to that.

Is it due to "System.Web" assembly that we can't deploy ASP.NET website on anything except IIS? I know, OWIN has replaced that in vNext.

Any help on deployment of previous versions of ASP.NET to Linux will be very appreciated.

Comment: It runs better with nginx in my experience.

Comment: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/06/setting-up-ubuntu-and-nginx-on-azure/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of ASP.NET, version 5, and more specifically the .NET Core, runs cross-platform. That's why there is a lot of information about running ASP.NET 5 (or vNext) on Linux with Kestrel, the new cross platform webserver for ASP.NET 5.

However, you can run older ASP.NET projects on Apache using, indeed, Mono. The official documentation can be found here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/#aspnet-hosting-with-apache and here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/